# Implementing a 24hour Countdown timer using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, timer, momentjs

Please I need help with implementing a 24 hours countdown timer in moment.js. here is my code :

```
<script>
window.onload = function(e){

var $clock = $('#clock'),

duration1 = moment.duration({
    'seconds': 30,
    'hour': 0,
    'minutes': 0,
    'days':0
});
duration2 = moment.duration({
    'seconds': 60,
    'hour': 0,
    'minutes': 0,
    'days':0
});

diff=duration2-duration1;
duration=moment.duration(diff, 'milliseconds');


interval = 1000;
setInterval(function(){    
    duration = moment.duration(duration.asMilliseconds() - interval, 'milliseconds');            
    $('#clock').text(duration.days() + 'd:' + duration.hours()+ 'h:' + duration.minutes()+ 'm:' + duration.seconds() + 's');    
 }, interval);
</script>
```

The problem is anytime I refresh the page the timer Refreshes also. How do I get around this. And if there is a much better way to implementing this please do share.

Thanks

Comment: You can either have a timer count down 24 hours from when the page loads, or you can count down towards a predetermined point in time; it sounds like you want the latter. If so you need to at least have that timestamp somewhere in your code

Comment: hello Aron, how will i create the timestamp so that it creates a 24hours stamp from current time

Comment: See my answer. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
// create the timestamp here. I use the end of the day here as an example
const end = moment().endOf('day'); 

setInterval(function() {
    const timeLeft = moment(end.diff(moment())); // get difference between now and timestamp
    const formatted = timeLeft.format('HH:mm:ss'); // make pretty

    console.log(formatted); // or do your jQuery stuff here
}, 1000);
```

This will print a timestamp out every second like this:

```
09:49:25 
09:49:24 
09:49:23 
09:49:22 
...
```

Comment: From this i can set the time i want as the timestamp and countdown from it. Thanks Aron.

Comment: Absolutely would do that

Comment: In my case, `diff` does not works in the correct way. So I tried several solutions and added as a reply.

Answer (score 2):

I think estimating time left logic might have a bug. The statement is `const timeLeft = moment(end.diff(moment(), true))`.

What I found was ...

```
const end = moment().endOf('day');                      // Mon Oct 22 2018 23:59:59 GMT+0900
const now = moment();                                   // Mon Oct 22 2018 14:38:30 GMT+0900
const timeLeft = moment(end.diff(moment(), true));      // diff = 33689322
const formatted = timeLeft.format('HH:mm:ss');          // 18:21:29
```

When you calculate with `Date` object, it will return 9 hours something. - I think that initializing moment object with diff returns causes this bug.

And this is the final form of my solution.

```
const end = moment().endOf('day');

console.log('End date', moment(), end, end.diff(moment()), moment().diff(end));
const timeLeft = moment.duration(end.diff(moment()));       // Use duration

const formatted =
  this.checkDigit(timeLeft.hours()) + ':'
  + this.checkDigit(timeLeft.minutes()) + ':'
  + this.checkDigit(timeLeft.seconds());        // checkDigit is a function which adds 0 to the numbers under 10
```

The major difference is `duration` function. Of course, it could be a version difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) to save the original timestamp.  Another option is to save it on the server (database?).  Either way, if you refresh the page, you will still count down to the same time.

Comment: hello Harry, if i do save the timestamp on the server how will I assign the timer for  users uniquely(assuming they clicked on a button).

Comment: It's back to saving some kind of id in the client's localStorage (or cookie).